# Jenkins - ssh connection exception

Tags: ssh, jenkins

This question may be asked multiple times but I need latest update on this issue.

I am trying to configure a slave for my jenkins Master but getting following exception:

```
ERROR: Unexpected error in launching a slave. This is probably a bug in Jenkins.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection is not established!
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.getRemainingAuthMethods(Connection.java:1030)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.TrileadSSHPasswordAuthenticator.canAuthenticate(TrileadSSHPasswordAuthenticator.java:82)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHAuthenticator.newInstance(SSHAuthenticator.java:207)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHAuthenticator.newInstance(SSHAuthenticator.java:169)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:1173)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:701)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:696)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[01/07/15 16:51:10] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[01/07/15 16:51:10] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Any idea of what's the issue here?

Comment: If this is a Jenkins bug, why not open a bug report in issues.jenkins-ci.org and track the bug in there? How did you determine this is a Jenkins bug and not a configuration problem on your part?

Comment: I am able to ssh VM using different machines. But getting exception in jenkins using same credentials.

Comment: Also, I have created a bug in jenkins too..

Comment: Please give us the pointer to the Jenkins bug report. (I'm hoping there would be some helpful details in the bug report because there definitely aren't any here.)

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26379

Comment: Please provide an exact description on how you provided the ssh credentials to Jenkins.